# Using Regex to replace space with newline in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, replace

I have the following string:

```
ABCD1234  ABCD1234
```

I'd like to replace the double space with newline, but preserve any text following the space

Here's what I'm trying:

```
.Replace what:="  *", replacement:=Chr(10), lookat:=xlPart
```

It does replace the space with newline, but removes the rest of string following the space

I'd like the replace action to only match cases where there is text after the string

Comment: Can you use subsitute?

Comment: You should also post a minimal code snippet, which would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Try to use `" +"`, so you won't replace an empty substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stops you from splitting upon double space and joining with vbNewline? i.e.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceSubstring()

Debug.print join(Split("ABCD1234 ABCD1234", "  ", -1,vbbinarycompare),vbNewline)

End sub
```

Does it reliably give you the output you want?

Comment: I should have thought of the Split and Join combination, it does exactly what I needed done!

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk `*` matches the rest of the text, so the rest of the text gets replaced.

You said you only want to replace the two spaces, so you shouldn't include the asterisk.

If you wanted to replace two or more spaces then AFAIK the Range.Replace function doesn't support actual regular expressions (where you could specify "two or more spaces") so you have to resort to using a RegEx library and manipulation of each cell through code (i.e. in code, iterate through the range cell by cell and apply a regex replacement to the cell's value using the VBScript RegEx library, for which you can easily google).

Edit: **Alternative using VBScript RegExp object**

As mentioned above, to use actual regular expressions, you can iterate the cells yourself and use the VBScript RegExp object to do the replacement. The following finds cells in the active sheet with characters followed by two spaces followed by characters and replaces the two spaces with Chr(10).

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "([^ ]+)  ([^ ]+)"
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Value = regex.Replace(cell.Value, "$1" & Chr(10) & "$2")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to add the VBScript Regular Expressions library to the project's references.

Comment: In this case, how can I tell the replace action to only match cases where there is text after the space, while preventing the rest of the text from getting replaced?

Comment: @Dan - you can't. Excel's Range.Replace function does not use regular expressions and doesn't support "find two spaces followed by text". You will have to go with iterating through the cells yourself and applying the RegExp object. I'll add to the answer...

Comment: Just tried and works great! I had a very specific case of double space where I find split & join simpler to use, but the iterating option will definitely be useful for me in other instances utilizing regex